# How can I load associated records the first time they are accessed in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a computed property, which fetches an associated record and tries to print it. The first time I fetch the record, it's null. All subsequent accesses *work correctly*. It is set as 'async: true', but setting it as false doesn't change this behavior.

```
MyApp.ThingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    myProperty: function() {

        var content = this.get('content');

        return content.filter(function(thing) {

            console.log(thing.get('title')); // Since this is a direct attribute on the model, it prints fine.
            var associatedThing = thing.get('associatedThing'), otherThings = [];
            console.log(associatedThing.get('content')); // This is a hasMany attribute on the model, and is null the *first* time, but fine on subsequent accesses.

            otherThings = associatedThing.get('content'); // Obviously doesn't work the first time either.
            return thing.get('title') + otherThings[0].get('name'); // Or similar.

        });

    }.property('content.@each') // adding observers for content.associatedThing.@each does not seem to make any difference.
});
```

Models are like:

```
MyApp.Thing = DS.Model.extend({

    title: DS.attr('string'),
    associatedThings: DS.hasMany('associatedThing', { async: true })

});

MyApp.AssociatedThing = DS.Model.extend({

    name: DS.attr('string')

});
```

Obviously, I cannot use promises here since I need to return a value from the function, so I cannot use a callback (since we're in a computed property.) How can I make this work the first time this associated record is accessed?

Edit: **myProperty** is a computed property on an **ArrayController**, and is used for showing or hiding **Things**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was simply to access the associated data in the ArrayController's init method:

```
init: function() {

    var content = this.get('content');
    content.forEach(thing) {

        // Prime the data.
        var associatedThings = get('associatedThings');

    });

}
```

This makes everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *can* use a promise, just not in the way you're thinking. For hasMany relationships, Ember-Data returns a [PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html). That means that it returns a promise that will resolve to an array. But in the meantime, the proxy will actually respond to `get` requests that you make with `undefined`. Then, when the promise resolves, any observers are fired. So, if you have your property depend on the `associatedThings` property, it *will* update when the promise resolves. In other words, this will work as expected:

```
MyApp.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    associatedThings: DS.hasMany('associatedThing', { async: true }),
    sum: function() {
        var things = this.get('associatedThings');
        return things.filter(function(thing) {
            return shouldFilterThing(thing);
        });
    }.property('associatedThings.@each.size')
});
```

Also, please don't be bugged by the fact that this doesn't happen synchronously. Trying to change it from asynchronous to synchronous will just make your code that much more fragile. Let Ember do its job and handle all of the properties and bindings for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added additional information to the original post to clarify what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: I put my property in the model, but it could just as easily go in an ArrayController. The same concepts apply. Watch the properties you want, and Ember will be sure they're updated when they need to be.

Comment: Hm, not working for me. It's still null the first time, and present on subsequent ones.